# How to block out a div for a certain IP address

Tags: asp-classic

I have to block out a certain div for a certain IP addresss 
I am using asp here is the code:

```
 <%
Dim sBlockedIP
sBlockedIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
'check if the IP is the one that is blocked
If sBlockedIP = "00.000.00.00" Then
'if IP address is banned then redirect to no_access.asp
Response.Redirect "no_access.asp"
End If
%>
```

this is the html that needs to be blocked to this IP

```
    <div id="social_media_outer">
      <div id="social_media">
      <div id="fb-root"> <script src="#">
      </script><fb:like href="" send="true" layout="button_count" 
show_faces="false" action="recommend" border="6" font="">
      </fb:like>
      <span  class='st_linkedin' >
      </span></span>
      <span  class='st_facebook' >
      </span>
      <span  class='st_sharethis' st_title="#"></span>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/share" data-count="none"><img src="#" style="position:relative;
      bottom:-4px; border:none;" /></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><span class="st_email" ></span>
      <a href="javascript:print(document)"><img src="http://www.gosh.org/facebook/sharethis/print_icon.gif" style="position:relative;
      bottom:-4px; border:none;" /></a>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Response.Redirect` is not the appropriate tool if you only wish to block a part of the generated content (and to block the whole page using IIS IP based security tools would be better than coding it).

This would do it

```
 <%
      Function CanShowProtectedContent()
           CanShowProtectedContent = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") <> "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      End If
 %>

 ...

 <div id="social_media_outer"> 
 <% If CanShowProtectedContent()  Then %>
    <!-- your normal content here -->     
 <% Else %>
    <span>Content unavailable</span>
 <% End If %>
 </div>
```

Although you should consider beefing up `CanShowProtectedContent` to support a list of bannedIP addresses and/or subnets. Also store the set as an ASP include file.

Comment: Thanks i will give this a go, but my asp skills are not very good at all to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put in a simple `If Else`?

```
If sBlockedIP <> "123.456.789.000" Then

   <div id="social_media_outer">
      <div id="social_media">
      <div id="fb-root"> <script src="#">
      </script><fb:like href="" send="true" layout="button_count" 
show_faces="false" action="recommend" border="6" font="">
      </fb:like>
      <span  class='st_linkedin' >
      </span></span>
      <span  class='st_facebook' >
      </span>
      <span  class='st_sharethis' st_title="#"></span>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/share" data-count="none"><img src="#" style="position:relative;
      bottom:-4px; border:none;" /></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><span class="st_email" ></span>
      <a href="javascript:print(document)"><img src="http://www.gosh.org/facebook/sharethis/print_icon.gif" style="position:relative;
      bottom:-4px; border:none;" /></a>

 </div>
</div>
</div> 

Else

End If
```

I may be really oversimplifying this...

Comment: Thanks i will give this a go, but my asp skills are not very good at all to be honest.